# Cant see include .h file symbols with intellisense, C project in WSL2

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include, intellisense, wsl-2

I am opening a C project directory in WSL2 using VS Code.  I have the C/C++ 1.21 extension installed, and Remote-WSL 0.53.4.

All my .h files are there in the project explorer.  The source .c file being edited has an #include "includes.h"  which lists them all.  Yet vscode intellisense does not see the contents.

Clues: if I attempt to add a lib, such as #include "./xzy   intellisense offers up files in Windows compiler directory, not my local project directory.  I think this is why.

Someplace VS is not reading my local directory as default, but some other compiler path that I dont use.
[image]

I dont speak json, so if you know how to manually configure vs to do this, be very clear and simple.  And remember my local paths are in wsl, so like
\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\me\work  have to work

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but I would generally consider having an include that just includes all your includes to not be great coding style. You should generally only include what you need.

Comment: please do not post images.  Rather copy+paste the actual text into your question